# Aggregate variance function and Hurst parameter

Tags: variance, aggregation, fat-tails, long-range-dependence

What is the aggregate variance method for estimating the value of Hurst exponent?
How does it measure long range dependence?

Comment: Where did you hear about it? Could you cite your source?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fArma/fArma.pdf  This package of R lists it as one of the function for computing Hurst exponent. Page 13